# Firestore only lets me load one document

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

So, why can I call any pair of key-value from [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMbQH.jpg), but can't from [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2WR7.jpg)?

This is my code

```
 var firstKitList = mutableListOf<String>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kit_list)

    val mainKitList = kitListView
    val mainListViewAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, firstKitList)
    mainKitList.adapter = mainListViewAdapter

     db1.collection("cities").get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        for (document in snapshot.documents) {
            val data = document.data
            val country = data["USA"] as String

            firstKitList.add(country)



        }
        mainListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

If I switch "cities" for "KitList" and `val country = data["USA"] as String`  for `val rope = data["skipping"] as String` it works... Could anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: In your firestore data I don't see data for key "USA" and "skipping". Are you sure that this data are correct?

Comment: That answer just made me figure out the problem. Thanks

Comment: Could you tell me one thing I don't know how to do: Instead of looking for a specific data, how can I load the whole document? Thanks

Comment: look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

1st Answer:
In your firestore data I don't see data for key "USA" and "skipping". Are you sure that this data are correct?

Answer for 2nd question.
I suggest you to create data class with fields you want. Then, you can map your document data to your class with code:

```
document.data.toObject(DataClass::class.java)
```

Or, if you have more than one document in QuerySnapshot:

```
val dataList = mutableListOf<DataClass>()
querySnapshot.documents.mapTo(dataList) { it.toObject(DataClass::class.java)}
```

Basing on your code, you can do this:

```
querySnapshot.documents.mapTo(firstKitList) { it.toObject(DataClass::class.java)}
```

@Edit1
this is you data model:

```
class City(var cityId: String,
       var state: String,
       var name: String,
       var country: String) {

    //remember to add empty constructor.
    constructor() : this("", "", "", "")
}
```

When you tap on list on this item, create an Intent with all this data, and start new activity.

@Edit2
If you want to add document with specific id:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("collectionName")
                    .document("documentId, for example LA").set(city)
```

If you want to pass id to previous activity, learn something about startActivityForResult method :)

Comment: regarding the first question, it was a stupid mistake, fixed. I was calling the value and not the key (data). As for the 2nd, maybe I explain myself wrong. Let's take the example of the collection "cities". I have a Document called "LA". How can I make it so on my List it shows "LA" and then I click on it and it appears with the elements inside that document? I know how to create an intent and all that, just need help with the part of getting it from firestore Thanks :D

Comment: Put document id (in this case LA) into document. Then you will have { 'country' : 'USA', 'name' : 'Los Angeles', 'state' : 'CA', 'cityId' : 'LA' }. It will give you ability to querying items by id :)

Comment: into document where? Sorry I am fairly new to Android Dev.

Comment: In your document you have 3 fields right? Put another one, call it cityId and add LA or another id you want :)

Comment: Oh no  no, not that :) What I want is for the Name of the Document (which in this case is LA, as you can see from the link on my question) to appear on my list and then when I click on it, another activity comes up with the data inside the document. As I said, I know how to create an intent :)

Comment: You cannot get list of ids from collection. My solution gives you what you want. You can get the id of the city from snapshot, then you can start another activity with this id, or you can provide more params (to reduce database usage for example).
If you don't want to do this that way, you can create new document with ids.

Comment: Oh I see... i could create a document solely for the ids, correct? Could you elaborate a bit more regarding your answer? As in how to show all the data inside my document? :) You're being very helpful thanks :)

Comment: Right. But I checked in the docs, each document has field called id. So you can get this id calling (according to your code): document.id .
In that case you are downloading entire list of cities, so you can use this data in the future (no needed to download them again for selected city).
It's better to store cityId inside city document :)

Comment: Got it... what about the second part? :)

Comment: @MilliyY about storing ids in documents?

Comment: This might be related: I have something like this https://imgur.com/a/VXHGR (saw on stack). How can I go around saving it to my firebase and upload (automatically) the name of my Created list to my list (the one I showed you on my question) - I did try something but the code was full of errors

Comment: no. About showing up all the data inside a document on a list (because like I said, I would touch "LA" on my list, and create an intent to load everything inside it)

Comment: I tried something like  Firestore.firestore().collection("Collection").addDocument(data: [
            // start out with the strings, then add constants.
            "FieldName" : "FieldValue",
            "FieldName" : "FieldValue",
            "FieldName" : "FieldValue"
        ]) { (err) in
            if let err = err {
                debugPrint("Error adding document: \(err)")
            } else {
                // successful do something
            }
        }               but it didn't work

Comment: So I add querySnapshot.documents.mapTo(firstKitList) { it.toObject(DataClass::class.java)} inside my Create List button?

Comment: @MilliyY it will map all documents inside snapshot to your custom list of models (I posted example of your model in my answer above). You can do with your list what you want.

Comment: There are a couple of things i don't get, but others that I do. Let me go one at a time and see if I am right/wrong. So, 1st I create a Data Class like you've shown me; after I add an intent to an item on my list and pass the information on that Data class inside that activity correct?  2nd: so if I want to add the name of my created list using the button I have to do it with startActivityForResult? instead of this  val intent = Intent(this, NewKitListActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent); correct?

Comment: And also, whats the difference between creating a data class and this FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("collectionName")
                    .document("documentId, for example LA").set(city)     ?

Comment: I have to go. Later I will post you git repo with all code you need to do this, ok?

Comment: Take your time. I am going as well now. Thanks a lot Skye, will be waiting :) On the meantime I will work ou ton something

Comment: Any news @Skye? :)

Comment: @Skyie, no worries at all :D Meanwhile I am going to study about  startActivityForResult. Thanks for your tips. See  you tomorrow

Comment: I will be on as much as possible to check your edits :)

Comment: @MilliyY today at 7 pm (GMT) I'll post here a link to repo.

Comment: not sure I will be on but I will definitely see it tomorrow at 9am (GMT). By the way, any questions you want answered to be clarified? Once again thanks a lot

Comment: @MilliyY https://github.com/banaszeknorbert/FirestoreCities It's not completely finished :)

Comment: Good morning @Skye, i am going to have a look :)

Comment: @ Skye, any chance we can chat on Skype or something like that? :) I have some questions thanks

Comment: @MilliyY write me an email (you can find email adress in profile on github).